# Angular Toggle Button on more than 1 line

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I want to implement a few angular toggle buttons. I don't exactly know how many, that depends on my database data.

The buttons are shown on a sidebar, which means that only up to 3 buttons can be rendered in one line.

Is there a way to break to a new line after e.g. 3 buttons ? Without creating a new mat-button-toggle-group ?

Here's my code:

```
      <mat-button-toggle-group multiple name="categories_1" ngModel aria-label="Kategorien">
        <mat-button-toggle value="LOREM1_1" checked>Value1</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="LOREM1_2" checked>Value2</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="LOREM1_3" checked>Value3</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="LOREM2_1" checked>Value4</mat-button-toggle>
      </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex` for this.

```
<mat-button-toggle-group fxLayout="row" multiple name="categories_1" ngModel aria-label="Kategorien">
    <mat-button-toggle fxFlex="33%" value="LOREM1_1" checked>Value1</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle fxFlex="33%" value="LOREM1_2" checked>Value2</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle fxFlex="33%" value="LOREM1_3" checked>Value3</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle fxFlex="33%" value="LOREM2_1" checked>Value4</mat-button-toggle>
    ...
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Or you can also loop through with `*ngFor` in case of unknown number of items, and still use the 33% flex width to get 3 items per line. You can adjust the width% to get more or fewer items in a single line.

Comment: This works for me when using fxLayout="row wrap" instead, though the look becomes a bit wonky (messed up border lines, and extra space on right unless you do fxFlex="33.33%")